# Cant redeploy to AWS with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

So I recently went through the process of transferring my domain and website from godaddy to AWS, and it has been nothing but problems. I have uploaded my .Net project to AWS with just a manual upload, and I got a 403 error. So I am now going through the AWS Toolkit option with Visual Studio. I have my account linked and when I click publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk it will show my environment, but when I click redeploy to that environment the buttons dont enable. I thought I was smart enough to be able to click a button, but apparently not. Here is a screenshot of what im talking about.
[image]
As you can see all the continuing buttons are disabled. I have absolutely no idea why and I have tried googling a variety of things but no luck. Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could your access key be expired?

Comment: @DanielA.White I just made it today, so no.